# Modify XP theme (appearance&color scheme) from a vbscript

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp, installation, themes

Does anybody know how to modify Windows XP appearance and color scheme using VBScript?

I have an application written in Visual C++ that needs Windows XP appearance (not classic) to be properly displayed and I want to set this properties from the Installation.

I use InstallShield to make the installer and VBScript to perform some custom actions. So it would be great if I can create a script in visual basic to change this properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was creating a c++ dll that I use as a Custom Action in Install Shield. In this dll I use the uxtheme.dll to set the luna.msstyle file as a theme. This is the function that does the work:

```
bool SetVisualStyle()
{
    TCHAR szUxTheme[MAX_PATH+1];
    UINT nSize = ::GetSystemDirectory(  szUxTheme,
                                        MAX_PATH);
    szUxTheme[nSize] = '\0';

    wcscat_s(   szUxTheme,
                MAX_PATH - nSize,
                L"\\uxtheme.dll");

    HMODULE hModule = ::LoadLibrary(szUxTheme);
    if(!hModule)
    {
        return false;
    }

    typedef int (__stdcall *SETVISUALSTYLE) (   LPCWSTR szTheme, 
                                                LPCWSTR szScheme, 
                                                LPCWSTR szFontType, 
                                                int nReserved);
    SETVISUALSTYLE pFnSetVisualStyle;
    pFnSetVisualStyle = (SETVISUALSTYLE)GetProcAddress( hModule,
                                                        MAKEINTRESOURCEA(LOWORD(65)));
    if(pFnSetVisualStyle)
    {
        pFnSetVisualStyle(  L"C:\\WINDOWS\\Resources\\Themes\\Luna\\luna.msstyles", 
                            L"NormalColor",
                            L"NormalSize",
                            1|32);
    }

    ::FreeLibrary(hModule);
    return true;
}
```

It's not perfect but it does what I need.

I hope that this can help someone else...if you have any doubt don't hesitate in asking me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
rundll32 shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL desk.cpl desk,@themes /Action:OpenTheme /File:"%WinDir%\Resources\Themes\Luna.theme"
```

However you still need to get the user to click "OK" or use another utility to do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change **individual appearance options** (like window colors), you can modify the appropriate registry values under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Appearance` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors` keys. For example, this code will chamge the window background color to cream:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.RegWrite path & "HKCU\Control Panel\Colors\Window", "255 251 240", "REG_SZ"
```

Note, however, that Windows will probably apply the registry changes only after reboot.

If you need to **load a ready .theme file**, you can use the following code:

```
Const Theme = "C:\MyTheme.theme"

Set oShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oShellApp.ControlPanelItem "desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""" & Theme & """"
```

Although, as sascha has pointed out, this will only bring up the Display Properties dialog with the specified theme selected; you still need the user to click OK or press Enter. It's possible to simulate key presses from script code using the [`WshShell.SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx) method:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Wait until the Display Properties dialog is opened
While Not oShell.AppActivate("Display Properties")
  WScript.Sleep 500
Wend

' Send the Enter key to close the dialog and apply the theme
Do
  oShell.SendKeys "~"
  WScript.Sleep 500
Loop While oShell.AppActivate "Display Properties"
```

But this approach is unreliable, because the user could click somewhere else so Enter would go to another window. Also, the Display Properties dialog caption is locale-dependent.

Another option would be to use the `Theme.Manager` API provided by the themeui.dll library starting from Windows XP SP1, but it doesn't seem to work on XP SP2. Anyway, you can find sample code [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t315426.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
'Script name: yourtheme.vbs

'Object: Automate without command prompt the application of a Windows Theme by a VB script

'

'SCRIPT CONTENTS:

'Define Variables : 

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set WsShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")


'

'Define path for your file theme (put it on a network share and don't forget to apply "read and execute" ACL for your Users)

    Theme = "typeyoursharepath\typeyourtheme.theme"
    Theme = """" + Theme + """"


'Open Display Properties Windows, Select your theme and apply with keep focus on Windows

    ShellApp.ControlPanelItem cstr("desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:" & Theme)
    Wscript.Sleep 100
    WsShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    While WsShell.AppActivate ("Display Properties") = TRUE
    WsShell.AppActivate "Display Properties"
    Wend


'END OF SCRIPT
```

Applied successfully on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003R2 X86, and under Citix XenApp 4.6FP7 (OS: W2003R2X86 SP2) to apply Windows Embedded theme with blue background color more light.

Looks great on Citrix session user!

Integrated in user config GPO at user logon under Citrix XenApp.